# When should i call close() on SQLiteOpenHelper in an activity with multi Async db operations

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, sqliteopenhelper

I have a **FragmentPagerAdapter** activity that calls different methods to fetch data from  database for different pages on **onCreateView**.

I am using Async task to execute the database queries. Further when the activity gets populated with data i have the search option that uses the same async task to query database to fetch results

When should i call the close() on SQLiteOpenHelper ?

OnPause is one option or should i call open and close right before and after the individual database queries ?

What is the best approach

Comment: the best approach is to use a custom ContentProvider, then you dont have to close() at all, and you dont have to use any AsyncTasks

Comment: Even if you look at the official android example, they are not closing the database. So, the answer to your question is you'd better off not closing the sqlite database except only in onDestroy(). and if you're saying that might cause issues, I'd say no. at least for my app which has about 150K users it is not causing any issue.